# force https rewrite rule for Magento website

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using Magento websites done with cname and mod rewrite.
Now I installed SSL - but I'm not getting correct links.
How to change the rule to force https for it

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*domain\.pl [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:kidsmobpl]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*domain\.pl [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]
```

Live Example:
 The problem is especially with 2nd website - that is affected by the rule above
https://kidsmob.pl
https://kidsmob.com

Home page links are https, but deeper navigation links are still http.
I use Cloudflare - force it to use https with page rules - but this is not working for deep links (magent uses relatives so this is strange).
http site is still visible instead using 
My Magento settings: prntscr.com/6pe2k2

Comment: Refresh Cache once and check if compilation is on

Comment: This was not helpful. I asked strictly how to exchange all trafic from http to https. Now I'm using rule above to load correct storeview - but it doesn't change auto-change user url from http to https Thanks if anybody could help with correct one.